# Change email logo for multistore

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, email, email-templates

I got a nice slogan for my store but I need to translate it in the other store languages. How do I change the email logo for different stores?

For example if the user has chosen english  in `English storeview -> System -> Configuration -> Design` and changed my email logo. But I still get the default logo. I also tried `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="email-header-sales" }}` to replace the header - but my complete layout got destroyed by this. If I'm using a static block for the footer, it works fine. Magento 1.9+ rwd theme. Thank you

Comment: When editing your store email logo under `System > configuration > Transactional Emails` which configuration scope is selected. This is located at the top left column

Comment: Ok the thing is - If you edit the email in the emails transactions you will see always the default logo but when you actually get the email it will switch to the choosen one.

Comment: I think that's because when your viewing transactional emails from the admin panel it will always load the default store config.

Comment: Can I fix this?`

Comment: You might be able to by creating a custom module that previews the template in a particular store view.

Answer (score 2):

One of the teams on a hackathon built an extension to preview the emails better (means: with real content):

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/E-MailPreview